# Tab space issue

Tags: php

I made a simple query system through mySQL which is showing me 100 records and I fetch them into my game but I have probelm with the codes in PHP.

I want to have 5char space between each row So I have to use tab space (`\t\t\t\t\t`), But I have a problem with this current system (e.g If I have field with two diffrent string value 10char and 2char then use tab space to make space between them I get different results:

`2Char string + 5char space = 7Char` and `10Char string + 5Char space = 15Char`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `scores` ORDER by `score` DESC LIMIT 100";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);  

for($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++)
{
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     echo $i+1 . "-" . "\t\t Name: " .$row['name'] . "\t\t\t\t Device: " . $row['device'] . "\n \t\t Difficulty: " . $row['level']. "\t\t\t\t Score: " . $row['score'] . "\n\n";
}
```

**Codes Output**

```
1- Name: James   Device: HTC OneX
  Difficulty: Hard    Score: 5760

2-  Name:  Erika_S      Device: PC
  Difficulty:  Normal       Score: 13780

...
```

**My Desired Output**

```
1- Name: James          Device: HTC OneX
   Difficulty: Hard     Score: 5760

2- Name: Erika_S        Device: PC
   Difficulty: Normal   Score: 13780
...
```

Comment: You shouldn't use tabs, since their actual width _widely varies_. If this is going to a browser, have you considered using HTML tables?

Comment: If you still need to use tab characters, be sure to count the text before deciding how much tabs to show. That said, sometimes you'd be better off with spaces if you don't know how much size (space) a tab character will use. I'm also assuming you're using a monospaced font...

Comment: Do you know &nbsp; and str_repeat?

Comment: @Airzooka No this is not going to a browser So I can't use HTML tables, Beacause my Game Engine does not support HTML tables.

Comment: @Christian Code you showing me this in example please ?

Comment: @Oliver No! Can you get me an example.

Comment: So you're wanting to send raw data to your game. You should output your data _like_ a table, and parse it with your game engine. You're on the right track with using characters between each set of data -- but instead of _5 tabs_, use _1 character_ like a pipeline ( __|__ ).

Answer (score 1):

`Tab` in fact is one char, but displayed in the way that user want. When, for example, in IDE you choose 8 spaces for 1 tab you will get it. There's a fantastic concept called [elastic tabstops](http://nickgravgaard.com/elastictabstops/), but it's only concept - so sad.

Conclusion: you can't do it what you described with `tab`.

What you can do:

- Calculate needed spaces and hardcode with `&nbsp;`, but it's dirty and you shouldn't do this.
- Use html tables

Comment: Thanks, But I can't use html tables.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $row['...'] use sprintf("%-15s", $row['...']), but in each place you'll need to adjust the number (-15) to what's really needed

```
<?php
$s = 'monkey';
$t = 'many monkeys';

printf("[%s]\n",      $s); // standard string output
printf("[%10s]\n",    $s); // right-justification with spaces
printf("[%-10s]\n",   $s); // left-justification with spaces
printf("[%010s]\n",   $s); // zero-padding works on strings too
printf("[%'#10s]\n",  $s); // use the custom padding character '#'
printf("[%10.10s]\n", $t); // left-justification but with a cutoff of 10 characters
?>
The above example will output:
[monkey]
[    monkey]
[monkey    ]
[0000monkey]
[####monkey]
[many monke]
```

read more at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

if you can't use printf, you can easily create your own function that does something similar, and is enough for what you need:

```
function add_spaces($str, $total_len) {
    return $str . substr("                           ", 0, $total_len - strlen($str));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I use printf(...); my game engine return me an error but it workes normally in browser.

Comment: well, reading your mind returns an error, but if you could post the error message we might be able to help :)

Comment: also my mistake, try sprintf instead of printf

Comment: I used Unity3d game engine and It has class which is called WWW, It's very complate class but It's limited on free versions license, When I use some specify function like printf() and... , It's return me an error which is said your version of unity is limited please purchase a full license to have this ability. :-(

Comment: so maybe you should purchase a full license, or state all this in your question, so 10 people are not trying to guess things they don't have a big chance to find out unless you give them the information

Comment: Yes you are right, I'm sorry. I'll Be Trying sprintf () and the inform you, Thank you anyway.

Comment: No, my friend told me that using auto-width fonts.

Comment: what fonts? can you post the solution please?